# Realizar un Order By a la información obtenida en la tabla

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimada Red,

Necesito ordenar la información obtenida en la tabla por el ID de manera ascendente, debido a que actualmente cuando me incorpora una nueva receta , incorpora su información de las primeras. Quiero además destacar, que el ID lo cree de manera incremental en la base de datos, por lo tanto es automático.

```
{this.state.data.map(reserva=>{
                            return(
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{reserva.ID}</td>
                                    <td>{reserva.CODIGO}</td>`introducir el código aquí`
                                    <td>{reserva.USUARIO.NOMBRE}</td>
                                    <td>{reserva.MESA.DESCRIPCION}</td>
                                    <td>{new Date(reserva.FECHA).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
                                    <td>{reserva.COMENSALES}</td>
                                    <td>{reserva.ESTADO}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>{this.seleccionarReserva(reserva);  this.modalInsertar()}}> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit}/></button>
                                        {"    "}
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>{this.seleccionarReserva(reserva); this.setState({modalEliminar: true})}}> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt}/></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                       })}
```